# Weird behavior of Bootstrap navbar-collapse with Animated.css

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, animation

Yesterday I implemented [navbar-toggle collapsed](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar) like this one in the example. Everything works great except one thing. When I dynamically add the `fadeInRight` or `slideInRight` class from [Animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) to some alement in the page, the whole top menu width is resizing according to page size (when an element is sliding from right the page width is changing).

To be clear, here is an example of my code:

```
<header class="navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1"> 
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#topmenu">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="">
                <img alt="" src="images/logo2.png">
            </a>
        </div>
        <nav id="topmenu" class="collapse navbar-collapse" role="navigation">
            <ul class="nav navbar-right navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="">ceník</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="">podmínky</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#contact">kontakt</a></li>   
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
```

All these classes are bootstrap classes.
Below is jQuery code which adds classes to visible element which should be animated.

```
// Plugin @RokoCB :: Return the visible amount of px
// of any element currently in viewport.
// stackoverflow.com/questions/24768795/
;(function($, win) {
    $.fn.inViewport = function(cb) {
       return this.each(function(i,el){
          function visPx(){
             var H = $(this).height(),
             r = el.getBoundingClientRect(), t=r.top, b=r.bottom;
             return cb.call(el, Math.max(0, t>0? H-t : (b<H?b:H)));  
          } visPx();
          $(win).on("resize scroll", visPx);
       });
   };
}(jQuery, window));

$("#references > div").inViewport(function(px){
    if(px) {
       var time = 0;
       $("#references > div").each(function() {
          var div = $(this);
          setTimeout(function(){ $(div).addClass("animated fadeInRight")}, time);
          time += 300;
       });
    }
});
```

And this is html which is animated.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<section id="references" class="row">
   <h2 class="col-xs-offset-1">Reference</h2>
   <div class="col-xs-10 col-lg-2 col-xs-offset-1 reference">
      <img src="images/sample1.jpg" class="img-circle" width="150" height="150">
      <article>
        <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Duis sapien nunc, commodo et.</p>
      </article>
   </div>
</section>
</div>
```

When I give `width` to `header` problem is solved. But I dont want fixed header width... Does somebody know how to fix it?